# Password wrong message in a login page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a login page for an admin portal, I want to display appropriate error message when password entered is wrong. I have developed the page in AngularJS. Someone who has already done this in AngularJS, please help me.

HTML for the login page

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <form class="form-signin">       
  <div class="form-signin-heading">
    <img src="Images/wellness-India-logo_0.png">
  </div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.emailid"   name="username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
  <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>      
  <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="login()">Login</button>  
  <button id="clear" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="reset">Clear</button> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Script for the login function

```
   $rootScope.login = function () {
    $("#blockUi").modal("show");
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.baseUri + "/adminLogin",
        params: {
            email: $rootScope.user.emailid,
            password: $rootScope.user.password
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (!data.found) {
            $("#blockUi").modal("hide");
        } else {
            $rootScope.fromLogin = true;
            $state.go('dashboard');
            $("#blockUi").modal("hide");
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });       
}
```

Comment: how we can resolve ur problem without code.

Comment: Yup, try to post a minimal example of what you already have, rather than all your code.

Comment: I have added the code that i have.

Comment: My answer below should solve this for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

hey it's full tutorial for validation in login page, Visit https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as form errors go, you should look into ng-messages: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

example:

```
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="pw" name="pw" ng-model="user.pw" placeholder="Password" ng-minlength="8" required>
    <div ng-if="signupForm.pw.$dirty" ng-messages="signupForm.email.$error">
      <div ng-message="required">Your pw address is required.</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength">Your pw must be at least 8 characters.</div>
    </div>
```

On the other hand, if you mean how to handle a "wrong password" error that is sent to angular from the server, I'd recommend using toastr .

It's easy and customizable. You just need to bower install it, then inject it: 
https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

In your js you'd check for an error. Perhaps in a .catch() after a promise, or conditionally if you're sending an error message in the response obj:

```
  $rootScope.login = function () {
    $("#blockUi").modal("show");
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: $rootScope.baseUri + "/adminLogin",
        params: {
            email: $rootScope.user.emailid,
            password: $rootScope.user.password
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (!data.found) {
            $("#blockUi").modal("hide");
        } else {
            $rootScope.fromLogin = true;
            $state.go('dashboard');
            $("#blockUi").modal("hide");
        }
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

       //handle error logic here: 

      //using toastr: 
       toastr.error(data);

      //traditional alert window MAKE SURE to inject "$window" into your controller
       $window.alert(data);
    });       
}
```

you may want to console.log('data', data) first to see exactly where the string is that you wish to display within the alert window. It may be in data.message, etc.

Also, you'll probably get chided for using $rootscope (considered bad practice).

Newer versions of angular do not use .success / .error , just the .then() and a .catch for errors.

Answer (score 0):

With a named from. You can set `ng-invalid` based on response

```
$scope.user.pw.$setValidity("pw", false);
```